# PHP Unserialize Offset Error

Tags: php, serialization

I have this code:

```
$serialized = $_POST['cartSer'];   
echo $serialized;
```

Which prints this:

a:1:{s:15:\"test\";s:3:\"999\";}

I then add this code:

```
echo unserialize($serialized);
```

And end up with this error:

Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 5 of 43 bytes in /mypage.php on line 5

What am I doing wrong with the unserialize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) enabled. Either disable them, or run your value through [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes)

```
$serialized = stripslashes($_POST['cartSer']);
```