# Cannot Unserialize String

Tags: php, serialization

Can someone tell me why this string won't unserialize?  I've tried just about everything (stripslashes, addslashes, trim, etc etc...)

```
a:10:{s:8:"order_id";s:13:"9006710350464";s:5:"buyer";s:10:"1303912674";s:3:"app";s:15:"223615011031939";s:8:"receiver";s:10:"1303912674";s:6:"amount";s:2:"20";s:11:"time_placed";s:10:"1326235812";s:11:"update_time";s:10:"1326235818";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:"item_id";s:4:"1_48";s:5:"title";s:49:"I\'m Not Jesus Mommy (Full Movie) - 48 Hour Stream";s:11:"description";s:204:"This is a purcahse to watch I\'m Not Jesus Mommy on FilmDemic Movie Streaming for a period of 48 hours. Once you complete the purchase, your account will have access to watch the movie for up to 48 hours.";s:9:"image_url";s:144:"https://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/wp-main/wp-content/themes/fd-fb-stream-wpf-child/library/images/titles/slidersize/im_not_jesus_mommy.jpg";s:11:"product_url";s:46:"http://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/film-1";s:5:"price";s:2:"20";s:4:"data";s:37:"film_id=1&wp_user_id=4&view_length=48";}}s:6:"status";s:6:"placed";}
```

I get "Error at offset 370 of 952 bytes", but that doesn't make sense, the "m" in Stream is the 370th byte.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, please display code as actual code and not plain text in your posts. The unformatted monstrosity of serialized data causes me to not even bother trying to answer your question.

Comment: @rdlowrey His problem is about unserializing bad data... it's not about code. How can you fix an error about a badly formatted serialized data if you can't see the data...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Unserialize Offset Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199491/php-unserialize-offset-error) - your serialized string is broken.

Comment: @hakre Could explain the first \ at position 370 but doesn't explain why there is a character missing at position 844 later :)

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I don't care **what the OP's problem is** if he/she/it can't be bothered to present it in a readable fashion. And last time I checked, a serialized output string still counts as code. It's worth noting that the question was subsequently edited to add some formatting ... which is likely why you found my comment misguided.

Comment: As always, for more informative error messages, just parse with [Serialized](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized).

Comment: Thanks everyone...  what tools do you guys use to inspect strings like this for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slash that shouldn't be there at position 324. Serializing data in PHP uses character counting. For example:

```
s:49:"I\'m Not Jesus Mommy (Full Movie) - 48 Hour Stream"
```

Says that there will be a string of 49 characters coming in the following quotes. But if you calculate correctly, there is a \ in this string that makes the count 50 character. If you tried to escape it, please unescape it to fix your issue.

There seems to be also another error after fixing this at position 844 which is the end of your product_url, it seems to be missing one character, probably a trailing slash in the url because the url is 45 characters long but it is expecting a 46 character long url...

So after correcting your serialized data i get this:

> a:10:{s:8:"order_id";s:13:"9006710350464";s:5:"buyer";s:10:"1303912674";s:3:"app";s:15:"223615011031939";s:8:"receiver";s:10:"1303912674";s:6:"amount";s:2:"20";s:11:"time_placed";s:10:"1326235812";s:11:"update_time";s:10:"1326235818";s:4:"data";s:0:"";s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:7:"item_id";s:4:"1_48";s:5:"title";s:49:"I'm
>   Not Jesus Mommy (Full Movie) - 48 Hour
>   Stream";s:11:"description";s:204:"This is a purcahse to watch I\'m Not
>   Jesus Mommy on FilmDemic Movie Streaming for a period of 48 hours.
>   Once you complete the purchase, your account will have access to watch
>   the movie for up to 48
>   hours.";s:9:"image_url";s:144:"https://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/wp-main/wp-content/themes/fd-fb-stream-wpf-child/library/images/titles/slidersize/im_not_jesus_mommy.jpg";s:11:"product_url";s:46:"http://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/film-1/";s:5:"price";s:2:"20";s:4:"data";s:37:"film_id=1&wp_user_id=4&view_length=48";}}s:6:"status";s:6:"placed";}

And it results into

```
array (
  'order_id' => '9006710350464',
  'buyer' => '1303912674',
  'app' => '223615011031939',
  'receiver' => '1303912674',
  'amount' => '20',
  'time_placed' => '1326235812',
  'update_time' => '1326235818',
  'data' => '',
  'items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'item_id' => '1_48',
      'title' => 'I'm Not Jesus Mommy (Full Movie) - 48 Hour Stream',
      'description' => 'This is a purcahse to watch I\'m Not Jesus Mommy on FilmDemic Movie Streaming for a period of 48 hours. Once you complete the purchase, your account will have access to watch the movie for up to 48 hours.',
      'image_url' => 'https://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/wp-main/wp-content/themes/fd-fb-stream-wpf-child/library/images/titles/slidersize/im_not_jesus_mommy.jpg',
      'product_url' => 'http://filmdemic.com/apps/fb-streaming/film-1/',
      'price' => '20',
      'data' => 'film_id=1&wp_user_id=4&view_length=48',
    ),
  ),
  'status' => 'placed',
)
```

Comment: That was it.  You nailed both right on the head.  I updated the sql database with a find and replace on the product url to alter them, not knowing how the serialize format works, thus generating the difference in string lengths.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank a lot for idea! stripslashes before unserialize helps.

Comment: I'm struck in awe how an escaped character can blow up the apparently pseudo-symmetric nature of serialize/unserialize. We're 2016, unserialize dates back from PHP4 which was launched in 2000 (!) Moreover, the silent fail is just a recipe for die/var_dump hell, which I just found out the hard way by having to debug someone elses WordPress plugin.